# PHP : Create unique id automatically when insert data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have "USERS" table like that :

```
============================
========== USERS ===========
============================
- id
- name
- surname
- avatar
- age
============================
============================
```

As you can see, the main key for each users is **"id"**.

When i want to add a new user in my table, i would like to insert automatically the good value of **"id"** in order to have a ***unique*** **"id"** for each user.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: use autoincrement for id

Comment: You are looking for the `auto_increment` functionality.  This topic has been covered many times and is well-documented.

Comment: enable AUTO_INCREMENT for id when creating table..

Comment: make id auto-incremented and insert without ID?

Comment: [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Also for uniqueness make it [Primary Key Constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html).

Comment: Ok, very simple ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment my id in my insert request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995719/increment-my-id-in-my-insert-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an auto incremented primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE `USERS` MODIFY COLUMN id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

When inserting data to the table, you just leave the id out, it will be inserted (and unique) automatically.